# how to copy linked file thru tcl

Tags: file, tcl, trace

I want to copy file thru tcl proggraming , these files are linked.
this is the code:

```
if { [file type $sfile] == "link" } {
        set fget [file readlink $sfile ]
         }        
      file copy -force $fget $dir
```

it works if the $sfile is a link. This does not work if the source file of the link is also a link.

how can I recursively trace the symbolic links?

Comment: There is the `fullnormalize` procedure from [tcllib's `fileutil` module](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc1.html)

Answer (score 2):

Recursive.

```
while {[file type $sfile] eq "link"} {
    set newfile [file readlink $sfile]
    if {[string index $newfile 0] ne "/"} {
        set newfile [file dirname $sfile]/$newfile
    }
    set sfile $newfile
}
file copy -force $sfile $dir
```

Comment: to be pedantic, that's iteration not recursion

Comment: thanks for your help, however it does not..errors out saying no such file or directory

Comment: I have file A that is linked to file B. file B is also a linked file, linked to file C.I want to copy file A to the a particular directory.

Comment: Are you sure that the link is not broken?  
If this is the case, then all Tcl magic will not help (an chroot is a common problem for that)

Comment: It's wise to set a limit on the number of link traversals you do (e.g., 10) so that you don't get stuck in an infinite loop. Or just `open` the two and use `chan copy` to ship the data between them (which won't copy other file metadata, but will move the contents if both files are resolvable to something real); in that case, infinite loops will get an OS error (errorCode: `POSIX ELOOP …`).

Comment: The function will not work for following links /path/to/the/file -> ../file 
You will get the following error: could not read "../file_link": no such file or directory

Comment: well, in that case you have to check first if the path is relative (e.g. no leading `/`).

Comment: There is a syntax error in current revision of the code, there is extra closing square bracket in the while condition {[file type $sfile] eq "link"]}, which causes syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have used this before. I have used the procedure to find the real file since the input given to us were link of links. Please let me know if this helps you.

```
proc get_real_link {linkfile} {    
    if {[file type $linkfile] eq "link"} {
       set tempfile [file readlink $linkfile]
    }
    if {[file type $tempfile] eq "link" } {
       get_real_link $tempfile
    } else {
       return $tempfile
    }
}

set realFile [get_real_link "new1.txt"]

#puts "$realFile" 
file copy -force $realFile $dir
```

Assumptions: new1.txt is the initial link file. There are no cycle links like A->B B->C C->A .

Comment: So this does basically the same thing that I do, add some unnecessary extra file type check, uses up the stack and has no other benefits than my solution? (Ok, your solution crashes when there are cycle links, my will simply go ahead and run along)